# Jenkins Weblogic deployer plugin context path setting

Tags: weblogic, jenkins-plugins

I have pom xml that builds - StudentEnrollment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
Building war: /root/.jenkins/workspace/StudentEnrollment/target/StudentEnrollment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
but the context path is /StudentEnrollment

As I could not find a way to specify the context path for weblogic plugin like in tomcat deployer plugin, for weblogic it is deployed with /StudentEnrollment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT as the context path .. I guess it is taking the war file name.

is there a way to set /StudentEnrollment as the context path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the context-root tag in a weblogic.xml file in your project to set the context root for a WebLogic deployment.

```
<context-root>StudentEnrollment</context-root>
```

For more information, take a look at the WebLogic documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WBAPP/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP623